# ORA-01019 connecting to Oracle from Excel Windows 7

Tags: windows, oracle, excel, odbc, ole

I was able to connect and query successfully yesterday in Excel on Windows 7
but I don't know what happened, now it is throwing me error 
.

```
ORA-01019: unable to allocate memory in the user side
```

I restarted PC, Cleaned cache, try connecting to database via Crystal reports and it works , tried connecting to database via SQLPlus and it works there too.

No Matter what I try to do it gives me unable to allocate memory in the user side even while setting up new connection.

Only gives me this error in excel.
I didn't make any changes to PC or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is Worst OS EVER.

I wasted my whole day on fixing this and it happens to be that.

```
I have to right click on excel and Run as Administrator. (from program files/....)
```

Good Luck.